# jQuery - scrollTop() after an anchor jump

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, anchor, scrolltop

I am wondering if its possible to get **$(this).scrollTop()** value after an anchor jump. Firefox manages it... however IE returns 0 as it retreives the value before page can jump to the anchor point (on page load).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `this` in that context? More code might help...

Comment: @nickdos this is just the window / document

Comment: What is the code that is being used to trigger that line? Have you tried JQuery `delay()`? http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: @nickdos thanks gave me an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
     IEScrollTop($(window).scrollTop());
}, 100);
```

That gave me the correct value for scrollTop().   thanks to @nickdos